# how to calculate the distances between all datapoints among each other

Tags: python, numpy, math

I want to check which data points within X are close to each other and which are far.  by calculating the distances between each other without getting to zero, is it possible?

```
X = np.random.rand(20, 10)
dist = (X - X) ** 2
print(X)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just `numpy` you can either do,

```
np.linalg.norm((X - X[:,None]),axis=-1)
```

or,

```
np.sqrt(np.square(X - X[:,None]).sum(-1))
```

Comment: can you explain the idea of adding a new dimension?

Comment: consider a simple case `[1, 2.]`. According to rules of broadcasting, if two arrays differ in dimensions, then the ones with the fewer dimensions will be repeated to match the dimension of the larger one. So in (X-X[:None]), since the dimension of the second param is more, it will make the first param repeat , there by making the actual subraction: ([[[1,2], [1,2]]) - ([[[1.],
       [2.]])

Comment: so if I add an extra dimension I could then calculate the distances with X and itself
is this the idea of adding a dimension?

Comment: yes, adding an extra dimension, forces the first array to repeat itself.

Comment: thanx, is there an efficient way to check if the distances between two point of all these points lie on the exponential function e to the power of -dist?

Comment: you can post that as a new question, so the accepted answer can benefit everyone.

Comment: would this solution also be the same if it was 3d array?

Comment: axis param will change for 3d array, `np.linalg.norm((X - X[:,None]), axis=(2,3))`

Comment: thank you, for this it's gonna be 
np.sqrt(np.square(X - X[:,None]).sum(2,3)), right?

Comment: can you please help me with this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74985697/reshape-2d-to-3d-array-under-specific-dimensions?noredirect=1#comment132327333_74985697

Comment: np.sqrt(np.square(X - X[:,None]).sum(axis=(2,3)))

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

X = np.random.rand(20, 10)
cdist(X, X)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go though each point in sequence

```
X = np.random.rand(20, 10)
no_points = X.shape[0]

distances = np.zeros((no_points, no_points))
for i in range(no_points):
    for j in range(no_points):
            distances[i, j] = np.linalg.norm(X[i, :] - X[j, :])

print(distances,np.max(distances))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you want a way to actually get some way of keeping track of the distances, correct? If so, you can easily build a dictionary that will contain the distances as the keys and a list of tuples that correspond to the points as the value. Then you would just need to iterate through the keys in asc order to get the distances from least to greatest and the points that correspond to that distance. One way to do so would be to just brute force each possible connection between points.

```
dist = dict()
X = np.random.rand(20, 10)
for indexOfNumber1 in range(len(X) - 1):
   for indexOfNumber2 in range(1, len(X)):
      distance = sqrt( (X[indexOfNumber1] - X[indexOfNumber2])**2 )
      if distance not in dist.keys():
        dist[distance] = [tuple(X[indexOfNumber1], X[indexOfNumber2])]
      else:
        dist[distance] = dist[distance].append(tuple(X[indexOfNumber1], X[indexOfNumber2]))
```

The code above will then have a dictionary **dist** that contains all of the possible distances from the points you are looking at and the corresponding points that achieve that distance.